# What's a regex to replace "(11245)"

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex for `String.replaceAll(...)` in Java to remove brackets and their contents.

For example:

```
 hello(100)
```

to:

```
 hello
```

Comment: What should happen for `(100(101)` and `a(b(c)d)e`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
theString.replaceAll("\\(.*?\\)", "")
```

Comment: Mike, please don't edit your answer back to `"\\(.*?\\)"`, it should be `"\\\(.*?\\\)"`. Otherwise I'm going to have to down-vote you! :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit Bart - of course, you are right. I tested the regex but forgot I had to escape the backslash when putting it into a java string. Too early in the morning... :-)

Comment: Adding the `?` makes the match reluctant, i.e. `.*` would gobble the closing bracket, and `.*?` wouldn't.